# I am not able to call a method of Main Activity from a class

Tags: java, android

I am not able to call a method of Main Activity from a class.
I am calling a method of Main Activity from a class then it gives an error is Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

this is my code

```
package com.example.romil.mypushexample;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

/**
 * Created by romil on 22/4/17.
 */

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    String message;
    String imageUri;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    String TrueOrFlase;
    API realtrackerApi;
    UserSessionManager sessionManager;
    MainActivity mActivity;


    public void getActivityObjetM(){
        mActivity=new MainActivity();
        mActivity.notificationAdded(true);
    }



    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        //Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
//        Log.i(TAG,remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        realtrackerApi=GlobalMethods.getRealtrackerAPI(this);
        sessionManager=new UserSessionManager(this);

        remoteMessage.getData();
        Log.i(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
            imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
            bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUri);
            TrueOrFlase = remoteMessage.getData().get("AnotherActivity");
            sendNotification(message, bitmap, TrueOrFlase);
            getActivityObjetM();
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image, String TrueOrFalse) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity", TrueOrFalse);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.testimage1)
                .setContentTitle(messageBody)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return bitmap;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my Main Activity

```
package com.example.romil.mypushexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ListView listView;
    UserSessionManager sessionManager;
    API realtrackerApi;
    ArrayList<GetNotificationListOutput> data;
    MyFirebaseMessagingService myFirebaseMessagingService;
    int listItemCount;
    Notification_Adapter adapter;
    boolean notificationStatus=false;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.notification_listView);
        sessionManager=new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        realtrackerApi=GlobalMethods.getRealtrackerAPI(this);

//        message=myFirebaseMessagingService.getMessage();
//        image=myFirebaseMessagingService.getImage();

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Push_Notification.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.showNotification).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RetroCallForGettingNotificationList();
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.refreshNotification).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RetroCallForGettingNotificationList2();
            }
        });

        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {

            for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);

                if (key.equals("AnotherActivity") && value.equals("True")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("value", value);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

            }
        }
        subscribeToPushService();
    }

    private void subscribeToPushService() {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");

        Log.d("AndroidBash", "Subscribed");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Subscribed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        // Log and toast
        Log.d("AndroidBash", token);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void notificationAdded(boolean status){
            RetroCallForGettingNotificationList2();
    }
}
```

Comment: `mActivity=new MainActivity();` It is not possible/permitted to create an instance of an Activity in this way. Not with `new` possible. `mActivity.notificationAdded(true);` If you make the method static you could call it with `MainActivity.notificationAdded(true);`. But if this of any use i dont know. I think it will not.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void getActivityObjetM(){
    mActivity=new MainActivity();
    mActivity.notificationAdded(true);
}
```

The above code is the wrong way to to do things.

You can use local broadcast managers for this.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("notification_received");
    intent.putExtra("status", value);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In your activity

```
private BroadcastReceiver message = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Do something with the intent
    }
};
```

for more info check [this](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-android-program-demonstrate-local-broadcast-manager/)

Comment: then how to call notificationAdded(); in class MyFirebaseMessagingService

Comment: I tried it but it is giving null pointer, java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.romil.mypushexample.NotificationAddedListener.notificationAdded(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: I don't want to intent any value, I just want to execute a method of MainActivity in class MyFirebaseMessagingService